# What types of large plastic sheets can I draw/paint on?

Tags: drawing, medium-selection, plastic

I typically draw on Stonehenge paper from rolls, cut size: 48" x 60+". I like working big but it's horribly expensive to frame anything that large so I have been looking into various plastic drafting films which are less fragile than paper and can be exhibited without framing.

Can anyone suggest types of plastics I could use? I have also been wondering about rigid sheet plastic too – that will stand up to being installed, moved, etc. That would be ideal. I use oil stick (which dries in 10,000 years, apparently), so I would likely have to adjust my medium.

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with seeking to expand your skill by trying new media. It may not be necessary, however. Maybe you can find a local crafter who can make frames for you. They can get additional exposure with labels on the frames, maybe even by mention in your marketing materials ("Frames proudly made locally by Mary Crafter"). Also possible to work out some in-kind trades for framing services with them.

Comment: This question is fine. I am just going to remove the explicit reference for brand. Most answers will likely touch on that anyway. In the end you are looking for materials not specifically where to get them which would be off topic as a shopping recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yupo](http://yupousa.com/what-is-yupo/), various [polyester-based drafting films](http://www.draftingsteals.com/catalog-paper--vellum--and-more-drafting-film.html) and [Tyvek](http://www.materialconcepts.com/tyvek/tyvek-art/) are some of the options I've found so far. Each has unique characteristics and all are (apparently) archival.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [lexan](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=lexan)? It's rigid and clear, holds its shape pretty well, comes in a range of thicknesses and can allow you to have layers in your work. I've made home-made white boards by mounting it on top of white paper but you could be more creative if you want to put different colors or pictures/collages, etc behind the lexan and draw on top. I don't have any experience using them with oil stick though, only white board markers. You could always coat in a clear sealant perhaps?